# I'm getting a TypeError on react-useanimations library calling for a toggle button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a component library and am intending to use of [react-useanimations](https://github.com/useAnimations/react-useanimations) libraries in that. But since I'm pretty new to React I need some help to understand how to implement toggle buttons and events.

The documentation on GitHub set [this example](https://github.com/useAnimations/react-useanimations#usage) for usage in controlled checkboxes - scrolling down, is the second one.

So I'm writing styled (SASS) components that I'd like to use in my library:

```
// ToggleButton.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import UseAnimation from 'react-useanimations';
import { checkBox } from 'react-useanimations/lib/checkBox';

/** @visibleName Botões de seleção 
  * @version 1.0.0b
*/

function Checkbox() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
  
  return (
    <div style={{ padding: '20px' }}>
      <span>Checkbox</span>
      <UseAnimation
        reverse={checked}
        onClick={() => {
          setChecked(!checked);
        }}
        size={40}
        wrapperStyle={{ marginTop: '5px' }}
        animation={checkBox}
      />
    </div>
  )
}


//** Radiobutton class to be writen here 
//** Togglebutton class to be writen here 

export {
  Checkbox
}
```

I'm using styleguided-framework. It renders a simple example of use, but in the case of this file, ToggleButton.js, I get this

> 'TypeError': "Cannot read property 'animationData' of undefined".

Not sure of what that means, but I'm guessing the attribute for which animation I'm calling is not going through the component UseAnimation. Not sure why, since I've used it - as in the third example in their GitHub in another project.

What am I missing? Can it be a function? Perhaps some hook I'm not understanding how to use?

Answer (score 1):

It happens that the problem was calling the component `<UseAnimation>`, which happens to be `<UseAnimations>` - plural - and importing it with {}. The correct form would be `import checkBox from 'react-useanimations/lib/checkBox'` since it's the default export.